# Global variable being modified inside function

Tags: javascript

I might be getting things wrong, but I know at least that I don't want this behaviour.

I have a while loop in JS, inside a function. Global vars are passed into the function.

Yet when the loop runs, the global variables are changed, alongside the ones inside the function.

Example

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var i = 0;

function test(myArr)
{
    while(i < 2)
    {
        myArr.pop();
        i++
    }

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(myArr);
}

test(arr);
```

The console spits out

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Why is the global being affected?

Comment: You're passing a reference to the object. `myArr === arr`

Comment: Because you *pop*'ed two of its members.

Comment: [This answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/962603) I think answers your question.

Comment: @George what do you mean? Where should I put myArr === arr?

Comment: @RobG I pop'd myArr, not arr.....

Comment: The value of *arr* is a reference to the array. You pass that value to *myArr* so they both reference the same array, hence `arr === myArr`. ;-)